# How to change the linewidth of a single line from a dataframe chart with many lines on matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, charts, linewidth

(stock_values / stock_values.iloc[0] * 100).plot(figsize=(10,6));
plt.show()

The chart has 20 stock lines and I wish to change the linewidth of only one.

I've scoured several alternatives, but none worked in a simple way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42759396. Get the specific line from the `Axes` and call `set_linewidth` on it.